# How to resolve 'Duplicate Entry' error in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to do a basic MySQL query. But when I run my code, it doesn't properly check if a record with that name already exists.

Here is my code:

```
            $loggedinUserID = $_SESSION['user'];
            $loggedinUserName = $_SESSION['name'];

            //check if user is logged in
            if(empty($loggedinUserID)) {header('Location: ../');}

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "{hidden}";
            $password = "{hidden}";

            // Create connection
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, '{hidden}');

            // Check connection
            if (!$conn) {
               die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            }

            $sql = "SELECT accessId FROM users WHERE userId=$loggedinUserID";
            $final = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($final);
            echo $result;

            if(empty($result)) {
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO users (`userId`, `userName`, `accessId`) VALUES ('$loggedinUserID', '$loggedinUserName', '0')";
                if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql2)) {
                    echo "Your account was created successfully, however you have not been permitted access. Please contact system admins to be granted access.";
                }
                else {
                    echo "An error occured when creating your account. --->" . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            }
```

When doing this it returns the error `An error occured when creating your account. --->Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'userId'`.

I know I have a record for this user already... But I do not know why it isn't detecting that record. Please help.

Comment: INSERT IGNORE INTO users (`userId`, `userName`, `accessId`) VALUES ('$loggedinUserID', '$loggedinUserName', '0')

Comment: where are you setting them session vars? it looks a bit backwards, user is logged in but then your adding a new user row as if its sign up.

Comment: How is the user already logged in, with an id in the session, if you're still trying to insert it in the table? Something is way off here.

Comment: @AntonioAbrantes, think the issue is more that it should not even get there if the user exists.

Comment: This uses Discord OAuth, which is how I already have an ID and username. But I want to check if I have records for them or not.

Comment: are you sure that there is no result ? echo $result is not properly to show an array, it would be better if print_r($result)

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `mysqli_error($conn);` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Answer (score 2):

The reported duplicate value `2147483647` can also be expressed as 2^31-1, which also happens to be the maximum value that can be stored by a 32-bit signed integer `INT` type in MySQL.

I suspect the datatype of `userid` column is INT (just guessing), and I suspect that the `INSERT` statement is attempting to provide a value larger than can be stored in `INT` datatype. MySQL behavior is to issue a warning and truncate the value down to the largest value that can be stored, and allow the statement to proceed.

I expect we would get different error with different setting of `sql_mode` to return a data truncation error rather than a data truncation warning.

Note that the SELECT won't generate a warning or error, checking for the existence of a row. It's just not going to return a row.

For debugging, consider echo/printf/vardump of the value being incorporated into the SQL text. (Also consider using prepared statement with bind placeholders as a way to mitigate SQL Injection vulnerabilities.)

---

As a demonstration of the behavior we observe in MySQL with values larger than can be stored in `INT`, consider:

```
USE test ;
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT PRIMARY KEY) ;
-- # 0 row(s) affected

INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (2147483648) ;
-- # 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s)
-- # Warning Code : 1264
-- # Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1

SELECT id FROM foo ;
-- #          id
-- # -----------
-- #  2147483647

SELECT id FROM foo WHERE id = 2147483649 ;
-- # 0 row(s)

INSERT INTO foo (id) VALUES (2147483649) ;
-- # Error Code: 1062
-- # Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'

DROP TABLE foo ;
-- # 0 row(s) affected
```

Answer (score 0):

'2147483647' is the maximum value for `int`. You need change your column `userId` on `bigint`.

Comment: Changing the datatype of the column could get involved if there are foreign key references.  Changing the datatype may fix the immediate problem, but that's really only kicking the can down the road til someone decides to POST a couple of forms with $_SESSION['user'] value greater than 2^63-1. Seems to me like the code could be changed so it detects values larger than can be stored in the userid column.